# Can't load remote placeholder image in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to load a remote placeholder image. The first image is a local image and loads properly, but not the second image. I am testing this on an android device so I don't think https would cause problems.

Any hints to what I might be doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, Image, ToastAndroid, Animated } from 'react-native';
import styles from "./styles";

class Story extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={};
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{position:'relative'}}>
                <Image source={require('app/assets/images/campus.png')} style={styles.container}></Image>
                <Image source={{ uri: 'https://place-hold.it/100x200/fdd.png' }} style={styles.character1}></Image>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
export default Story;
```

Answer (score 2):

// firstly set isImageload  false

then implement image like this

```
var image= this.state.isImageload ? require('place holder image') : {uri: ImageUrl};

return(
  <Image
    source={immage}
    onLoadStart={() => this.setState({isImageload : true})}  
    onLoad={() => this.setState({isImageload : false})}
  />
)
```

Answer (score -2):

I removed one pair bracket from the Image tag and the code become:

```
<Image source={ uri: 'https://place-hold.it/100x200/fdd.png' } style={styles.character1}></Image>
```

Please try it to see whether if works.